# Trimming trailing :00 from output after date_trunc

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I have the following SELECT where I'm subtracting two times from a table to see how long something took.

```
SELECT finished-started AS duration FROM table;
```

That gives me answers like *3 days 00:17:15.181635*

So then I used date_trunc because I only really care down to the level of minutes.

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', finished-started) AS duration FROM table;
```

That gives me an answer like *3 days 00:17:00*

Is there a way to trim off the :00 from the end so the SELECT will output something like 3 days 00:17?

Comment: You can use `to_char()` to format the interval

Comment: So in your column "finished-started" there is only this value : "00:17:15.181635" ?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Finished and Started are both columns that are timestamp without time zone. So my SELECT is subtracting them and giving the me the difference. Here is example output: DBNAME=> select id, started, finished, finished-started as duration from tablename limit 1;
 id |          started           |          finished          |        duration
  5 | 2019-09-06 18:16:50.773331 | 2019-09-06 18:28:08.109557 | 00:11:17.336226

Answer (score 1):

### Using `rtrim()`:

You do the `date_trunc()`, cast it to `varchar` and `rtrim()` the ending *:00* part:

```
SELECT 
    rtrim(date_trunc('minute', finished - started)::varchar(255), ':00') AS duration 
FROM table
```

### Using `to_char()`:

It gets a bit convoluted since the formatting options for `interval` type are limited.
You can use the `'DD HH24:MI'` formatting syntax, but it won't display you the *day/days* as units (e.g. you will get *3 00:17*). If it's fine, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(date_trunc('minute', finished - started), 'DD HH24:MI') AS duration
FROM table
```

If displaying *day/days* (e.g. *3 days 00:17*) are necessary, then you need to 'program' it manually - something like this:

```
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(day from finished - started) < 1 THEN 
            to_char(date_trunc('minute', finished - started), 'HH24:MI')
        WHEN extract(day from finished - started) > 1 THEN 
            to_char(date_trunc('minute', finished - started), 'DD "days" HH24:MI')
        ELSE
            to_char(date_trunc('minute', finished - started), 'DD "day" HH24:MI')
    END AS duration
FROM table
```